# Sleep(suspend) and Resuming windows form starts program on worker thread instead of main thread

Tags: sleep, resume, suspend, worker-thread, systemevent

The windows form I am working on subscribes to `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` and on `Suspend` it runs the `Close()` method on the form. On `Resume` it runs the `Run()` function like it would on initial load. The problem is that when the computer is woken from sleep mode the PowerModeChanged event is triggered on a worker thread named ".Net SystemEvents" and when `Run()` is called it recreates the form on this worker thread instead of the main thread.

This form is a project I inherited from another developer and I am new to windows form programming. I am wondering if there is a better way to handle the sleep/wake process rather than closing the forms and recreating them on wake or a way to force the creation onto the main thread. Note: If I remove the code and have it do nothing when the computer is slept (suspended) and nothing when it wakes (resumes) then the program continues to work correctly (running on the main thread). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: Why does it do that in the first place?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I imagine the original developer was wanting to handle sleep efficiently? As I stated, I haven't worked with windows forms before so I'm not sure what the best practices are for suspending/resuming a form.

Comment: I asked the original developer of this form and he says it is because the SDK the form is using will cause the program to crash.  This is because this form is a VOIP client and the SDK is what connects to the VOIP server. When the computer is suspended and resumed the SDK loses connection to the VOIP server and crashes.

Comment: Don't close the form; just stop the VOIP stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture the UI thread SynchronizationContext in a static field, and `Post()` on it to go back to the UI thread.

Comment: Ah, thanks SLaks. I tried to vote up the answer but don't have the rep yet. Will do once I've earned it.